# Java EJB Client connection via SSL port

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

My requirement is to connect an application deployed in weblogic server, i will use a shell script to invoke a java EJB client residing in the same server but i need to use via SSL port.

When i try connecting with non-ssl port the connection is established but when SSL port is used im getting the below error:
*"javax.namin.CommunicationException: Failed to initialize JNDI context, tried 2 time or times, the interval of each time is 0ms.
[Login failed for an unknown reason:P] [Root exception is weblogic.socket.UnrecoverableConnectException: [Login faile dfor an unknown reason:P]*

Current java client arguments doesnot include SSL parameters, please help on this how do i achieve this.

Comment: Did you achieve you ssl configuration in your weblogic server domain ? Did you call your EJB via the ssl port ?

Comment: Yes Weblogic domain is configured with SSL. Apps installed in the server are able to access via SSL port. EJB client is residing on the same as weblogic server do i need to import the certificate or pass as arguments when i try to connect using ssl listener?